# merge excel files with dynamic names

Tags: python, excel, pandas, concatenation

I have an Excel file that needs to be refreshed automatically every week. It must be extended by other Excel files. The problem is that these files have different names each time.
So in my opinion i can not use code like:

```
import pandas as pd 
NG = 'NG.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(NG)
```

because the filename is not always "NG" like in this case.
Do you have any ideas?

Best Greetz

Comment: Are these files all delivered in the same folder? And, do you wish to concatenate the new file's content to an existing df?

Comment: thanks for the answere! yes, they are all in the same folder. Yes, the existing Excel file should just get updated.

Answer (score 0):

You could read all the files in your folder by doing this, because it allows you to ignore name changes:

```
import sys
import csv
import glob
import pandas as pd

# get data file names
path = r"C:\.......\folder_with_excel"
filenames = glob.glob(path + "/*.xlsx")

DF = []

for df in dfs: 
    xl_file = pd.ExcelFile(filenames)
    df=xl_file.parse('Sheet1')
    DF.concat(df, ignore_index=True)
```

Alternatively:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

path = os.getcwd()
files = os.listdir(path)   # list all the files in you directory

files_xls = [f for f in files if f[-3:] == 'xlsx']  # make a list of the xlsx 

df = pd.DataFrame()

for f in files_xls:
    info = pd.read_excel(f, '<sheet name>')  # remove <sheet name if you don't need it
    df = df.append(info)
```